# How can I explicitly specify a value

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get the index of an element in a Spinner with the following expression where employeesList is a String Array and userName is the string value of the element in the spinner:

```
val itemPosition = Arrays.asList(employeesList).indexOf(userName)
```

In return I get the following error:

> "kotlin type inference failed. the value of the type parameter T
>   should be mention in input types (argument types receiver type or
>   expected type.(try to specify it explicitly)"

Comment: Where is that error, and what is `employeesList`?

Comment: The Wanderer please read carefully, everything is explained there. Thanks.

Comment: No, it isn't. That error is about a specific part of the line. I see the array type now, but the error location isn't specified in your question.

Comment: Also, are you sure `userName` is actually a String, not a CharSequence?

Comment: See what you mean, It's on "indexOf"

Comment: Try using `employeesList.asList().indexOf(userName)`

Comment: Yes, userName is a String

Comment: Can you just add the actual code of how `employeesList` and `userName` are defined? Either `employeesList` isn't actually a String Array, or `userName` isn't a String.

Comment: The Wanderer, you are right: employeesList is an ArrayList. Thanks for pointing that out. Will delete this question. Cheers

Comment: @RomanGolyshev `asList()` just calls `Arrays.asList()` internally.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, your `employeesList` was already a List, and not a String Array, meaning `Arrays.asList()` was creating an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>` with a single element.

To answer the type declaration question (although it wouldn't solve this issue):

```
val someInteger: Int
val someString: String
//etc
```

The type declaration goes after the variable name, following a colon.

Answer (score 0):

You've another option which is this one:

```
val indexOfItem = listOf("1","2","3").indexOfFirst { it == "3" }
```

So the value `indexOfItem` will be 2. The lambda is executed for every item, and the lambda must return true if it matches your search.